# Conditional with_items

Tags: ansible

I have two lists of items:

```
list1:
 - element1
 - element2

list2:
 - element1
 - element2
```

and a variable defined in `group_vars`

```
env: x #can be either dev or stg
```

And what I would like to perform is:

```
- name: Create database
  influxdb_database:
    hostname: xyz
    database_name: "{{ item }}"
    .
    .
  with_items: list1 if env is stg
  with_items: list2 if env is dev
```

If above is not clear, I basically want to run this task for items defined in list1, if `env` var for given hosts is set to `stg`, ELSE run it for items defined in list2 if `env` var for given hosts is set to `dev`.

How do I achieve such results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use if conditional like so,

```yaml
- name: Create database
  influxdb_database:
    hostname: xyz
    database_name: "{{ item }}"
    .
    .
  with_items: "{{ list1 if env == 'stg' else list2 }}"
```